# Changing address contained by structure and its members using function (ANSI C)

Tags: c, multithreading, struct, malloc

[EDIT]I added all my main code and some of the external functions used by this code. The code is quite long, but in summary it sends a message to a device measuring some parameters of the water in a container, and the device responds with the corresponding value measured by the sensor.
After that the code uses this value to modify the level and temperature of water. Prints the current status of the container and makes a log.txt file.[/Edit]

I want to do a constructor object-oriented-like function in C, but the address of my structure and its members are not being changed after I malloc() them. I saw this answer [Changing address contained by pointer using function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431108/changing-address-contained-by-pointer-using-function) and I got an idea of what my problem is, but still can't solve it.
Below is my code that is doing the constructor:

udp.c

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "udp.h"
#define BUF_SIZE 1000
#define HEADER_SIZE

typedef struct{
    int socket;
    char header[4];
    float *send_value;
    char *message_buffer;
}message;


void build_message(message **msg, int socket, char header[], float *send_value){
    *msg = (message *)malloc(sizeof(message));
    (*msg)->socket = socket;
    strncpy((*msg)->header, header, 4);
    (*msg)->send_value = send_value; 
    (*msg)->message_buffer = NULL; 
    (*msg)->message_buffer = malloc(BUF_SIZE);
    //(**msg).message_buffer = (char *)(msg+sizeof(int) + sizeof(float *) + sizeof(char *)*3);
}

int prepara_socket_cliente(char *host, char *porta)
{ 
    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *result, *rp;
    int sfd, s;

    /* Obtain address(es) matching host/port */

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;    /* Allow IPv4/ or IPv6 */
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM; /* Datagram socket */
    hints.ai_flags = 0;
    hints.ai_protocol = 0;          /* Any protocol */

    s = getaddrinfo(host, porta, &hints, &result);
    if (s != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(s));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* getaddrinfo() returns a list of address structures.
       Try each address until we successfully connect(2).
       If socket(2) (or connect(2)) fails, we (close the socket
       and) try the next address. */

    for( rp = result; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next) {
        sfd = socket(rp->ai_family, rp->ai_socktype, rp->ai_protocol);
        if (sfd == -1)
            continue;

        if (connect(sfd, rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen) != -1)
            break;                  /* Success */

        close(sfd);
    }

    if (rp == NULL) {               /* No address succeeded */
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not connect\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);           /* No longer needed */

    return sfd;
}

float receive_message(message *msg){
    ssize_t nread;
    int len;
    //sprintf(msg->message_buffer, "%s0.0", msg->header);
    len = strlen(msg->message_buffer)+1;
    int rc;
    if (len + 1 > BUF_SIZE){
        fprintf(stderr, "Ignoring long message in argument\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if((rc = write(msg->socket, msg->message_buffer, len)) != len){
        printf("%d, %d\n", len, rc);
        fprintf(stderr, "partial/failed write\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    nread = read(msg->socket, msg->message_buffer, BUF_SIZE);
    if (nread == -1){
        perror("read");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return atof(msg->message_buffer+3);
}

int send_message(message *msg){
    ssize_t nread;
    int len;
    //sprintf(msg->message_buffer, "%s%.1f", msg->header, *msg->send_value);
    len = strlen(msg->message_buffer)+1;
    int rc;
    if (len + 1 > BUF_SIZE){
        fprintf(stderr, "Ignoring long message in argument\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if((rc = write(msg->socket, msg->message_buffer, len)) != len){
        printf("%d, %d\n", len, rc);
        fprintf(stderr, "partial/failed write\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    nread = read(msg->socket, msg->message_buffer, BUF_SIZE);
    if (nread == -1){
        perror("read");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

main.c

```
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<errno.h>

#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<termios.h>
#include"controller.h"
#include"screen.h"
#include"myIO.h"
#include"my_time.h"
#include"data_structures.h"
#include"udp.h"

#define NUM_THREADS 5
#define MAX_PARAM_SIZE  20
#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 1200
//variables 
typedef enum {IDLE, QUIT, CHANGE_LEVEL_REF, CHANGE_TEMP_REF} command_type;
struct timespec t1;
struct timespec t2;
pthread_cond_t screen = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cmd = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t barrier = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
int count[2] = {0,0};
command_type command = IDLE;
double_buffer* log_buffer;
char* port = NULL;
char* host = NULL;;
int socket_cliente;
real Ta, Ti, No;
real T=0;
real H=0;
real Q=0;
real Nf=0;
real Ni=0;
real Na=0;
real href = 2.0;
real tref = 25.0;
pthread_mutex_t em_scan;
pthread_mutex_t em;

void init(){
    port = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_PARAM_SIZE);
    host = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_PARAM_SIZE);
    log_buffer = build_double_buffer();
}
//threads

void *LevelControl(void *threadid){
/**********************************************************
 *thread responsible for controling the water level
 *********************************************************/
    controller* levelControl = NULL;
    levelControl = build_controller();
    levelControl->kp = 10000.0;
    levelControl->ki = 0.0;
    levelControl->kd = 0.0;
    levelControl->error_thresh =  1.0;
    levelControl->step_time = 0.7;
    levelControl->max_actuator_value = 100.0;
    levelControl->min_actuator_value = 0.0;
    int intervalo = 90000000;
    message *message_H = NULL;
    build_message(&message_H, socket_cliente, "sh-", &H);
    sprintf(message_H->message_buffer, "%s0.0", message_H->header);
    message *message_Nf = NULL;
    build_message(&message_Nf, socket_cliente, "anf", &Nf);
    message *message_Ni = NULL;
    build_message(&message_Ni, socket_cliente, "ani", &Ni);
loop_1:
    if(command != QUIT){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&em);
        H = receive_message(message_H);
        levelControl->error = href - H;

        if(levelControl->error < 0.0){
            levelControl->error = -levelControl->error;
            Nf = PID_Update(levelControl);
            Ni = 0.0;
        }else{
            Ni = PID_Update(levelControl);
            Nf = 0.0;
        }
        sprintf(message_Nf->message_buffer, "%s%f", message_Nf->header, *message_Nf->send_value);
        send_message(message_Nf);
        sprintf(message_Ni->message_buffer, "%s%f", message_Ni->header, *message_Ni->send_value);
        send_message(message_Ni);
        count[1] = 1;
        if((count[0] == 1) & (count[1] == 1))   pthread_cond_signal(&barrier);
        next_timer(t1, intervalo);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&em);
        goto loop_1;
    }else return NULL;
}

void *TempControl(void *threadid){
/**********************************************************
 * thread responsible for controling the temperature
 *********************************************************/ 
    controller *tempControl = NULL;
    tempControl = build_controller();
    tempControl->kp = 10000.0;
    tempControl->ki = 0.0;
    tempControl->kd = 0.0;
    tempControl->error_thresh =  20.0;
    tempControl->step_time = 0.7;
    tempControl->max_actuator_value = 10000.0;
    tempControl->min_actuator_value = 0.0;
    int intervalo = 70000000;

    message *message_T = NULL;
    build_message(&message_T, socket_cliente, "st-", &T);
    sprintf(message_T->message_buffer, "%s0.0", message_T->header);
    message *message_Q = NULL;
    build_message(&message_Q, socket_cliente, "aq-", &Q);
    message *message_Na = NULL;
    build_message(&message_Na, socket_cliente, "ana", &Na);
    char *log_string = NULL;
        log_string = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);
//  while(command != QUIT){
loop_2:
    if(command != QUIT){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&em);
        T = receive_message(message_T);
        tempControl->error = tref - T;  
        Q = PID_Update(tempControl);
        sprintf(message_Q->message_buffer, "%s%f", message_Q->header, *message_Q->send_value);
        send_message(message_Q);
        if(Q == tempControl->max_actuator_value){
            Na = 10.0;
        }else if(Q == tempControl->min_actuator_value){
            Na = 0.0;
        }
        sprintf(message_Na->message_buffer, "%s%f", message_Na->header, *message_Na->send_value);
        send_message(message_Na);
        count[0] = 1;
        if((count[0] == 1) & (count[1] == 1))   pthread_cond_signal(&barrier);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&em);
        sprintf(log_string, "Temperura: %f\n", T);
        setDoubleBuffer(log_buffer, log_string);
        next_timer(t2, intervalo);
        goto loop_2;
    }else return NULL;
//  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *Status(void *threadid){
/**********************************************************
 *thread responsible for printing the current status on 
 *the screen and setting tref and href
 *********************************************************/
    message *message_Ta = NULL;
    build_message(&message_Ta, socket_cliente, "sta", &Ta);
    sprintf(message_Ta->message_buffer, "%s0.0", message_Ta->header);
    message *message_Ti = NULL;
    build_message(&message_Ti, socket_cliente, "sti", &Ti);
    sprintf(message_Ti->message_buffer, "%s0.0", message_Ti->header);
    message *message_No = NULL;
    build_message(&message_No, socket_cliente, "sno", &No);
    sprintf(message_No->message_buffer, "%s0.0", message_No->header);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&em);
    while((count[0] != 1) | (count[1] != 1))    pthread_cond_wait(&barrier, &em);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&em);
    //while(command != QUIT){
loop_3: 
    switch(command){
        case IDLE:
            pthread_mutex_lock(&em);
            clearScreen();
            Ta = receive_message(message_Ta);
            Ti = receive_message(message_Ti);
            No = receive_message(message_No);
            printf("/********************************************************************************************************\n");
            printf("*STATUS\n");
            printf("*reference temperature: %f\n", tref);
            printf("*reference water level: %f\n", href);
            printf("*current temperature: %f\n", T);
            printf("*current water level: %f\n", H);
            printf("*other sensor value => Ni = %f, No = %f, Na = %f, Nf = %f, Ta = %f, Ti = %f\n", Ni, No, Na, Nf, Ta,Ti);
            printf("*\n");
            printf("*\n");
            printf("*\n");
            printf("*(q)uit, change (l)evel reference, change (t)emperature reference\n");
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&em);
            sleep(1);
            break;
        case CHANGE_LEVEL_REF:
            pthread_mutex_lock(&em_scan);
            printf("insert new Level reference\n");
            scanf("%f", &href);
            pthread_cond_signal(&screen);
            while(command != IDLE){
                pthread_cond_wait(&cmd, &em_scan);
            }
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&em_scan);
            break;
        case CHANGE_TEMP_REF:
            pthread_mutex_lock(&em_scan);
            printf("insert new Temperature reference\n");
            scanf("%f", &tref);
            pthread_cond_signal(&screen);
            while(command != IDLE){
                pthread_cond_wait(&cmd, &em_scan);
            }
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&em_scan);
        case QUIT:
            fprintf(stderr, "get saiu\n");
            return NULL;
    }
    goto loop_3;    
    //return NULL;
 }



void *GetReferences(void *threadid){
/**********************************************************
 *thread responsible for changing the program mode
 *********************************************************/
    char temp;
    //while(command != QUIT){
loop_4:
    temp = getch();
    switch(temp){
        case 'q':
            command = QUIT;
        printf("%c\n --------------------------------------------------------\n", temp);
            return NULL;
        case 'l':
            pthread_mutex_lock(&em_scan);
            command = CHANGE_LEVEL_REF;
            pthread_cond_wait(&screen, &em_scan);
            command = IDLE;
            pthread_cond_signal(&cmd);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&em_scan);

            break;
        case 't':
            pthread_mutex_lock(&em_scan);
            command = CHANGE_TEMP_REF;
            pthread_cond_wait(&screen, &em_scan);
            command = IDLE;
            pthread_cond_signal(&cmd);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&em_scan);
        }
    goto loop_4;
}

void *Log(void *threadid){
    char *receive_buffer = NULL;
    receive_buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);
    //while(command != QUIT){
loop_5:
    if(command != QUIT){
        get_buffer(receive_buffer, log_buffer);
        write_log(receive_buffer);
        goto loop_5;
    }else return NULL;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    init();
    pthread_mutex_init(&em_scan, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&em, NULL);
    init_nano_timer(t1);
    init_nano_timer(t2);
    clearScreen();
    printf("Enter the port where to be used in the udp communication\n");
    scanf("%s", port);
    strcpy(host, "localhost");
    socket_cliente = prepara_socket_cliente(host, port);
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    int rc;
    int t;
    void *threadName[NUM_THREADS];
    threadName[0] = TempControl;
    threadName[1] = LevelControl;
    threadName[2] = Status;
    threadName[3] = GetReferences;
    threadName[4] = Log;
    for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++){
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, threadName[t], (void *)t);
        if(rc){
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++){
        rc = pthread_join(threads[t], NULL);
        if(rc){
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Btw, I am using threads in these code, would this code be thread-safe even without mutexes?

Comment: don't you need `char header[4];` to store `"sta"`?

Comment: In my message protocol I need a message that has 3 chars and a float concatenated eg. "sta3.0", so I guess not, should I?[edit] in fact in another function I `sprintf()` `msg.header` and `msg.send_value` to concatenate them and send them to `msg.message_buffer`. I am not sure if this is the most readable way to do this.

Comment: Also, why you're mallocing for those extra variable sizes? `sizeof(message)` should have sufficed, no?

Comment: Instead of `strcpy(msg->header, header);` ues `memcpy(msg->header, header, 3);`

Comment: @SouravGhosh you are right, I was doing `malloc()` and trying to allocate memory in sequence before, now I changed it. I got back to `malloc(message)`, but still not being assigned.

Comment: but if you use `[3]` only, where `strcpy()` should copy the null? As @LPs  mentioned, you can use `memcpy()`  with a `[3]` array, but I'd suggest, go for a `[4]` array, safer from accidental misue.

Comment: @LPs I changed that like you said. Maybe that is better because I am getting sure only 3 bytes are written to memory.

Comment: @LPs ok, I got the point, in a misuse I will probalbly get a segmentation fault telling me I should write longer than 3, I will change like you said

Comment: The code you presented should not even compile.  In `build_message()`, argument `msg` has type `message **`.  Statements such as `msg->socket = socket` should be rejected by the compiler: you want `(*msg)->socket = socket`.  That is, the pointer to your new struct is `*msg`, not `msg` itself.

Comment: @LPs I respectfully disagree. later, if that `header` is used as an argument to `%s` in `sprintf()`, it'll get UB.

Comment: @SouravGhosh better use `strncpy(msg->header, header, 4)` after moving header to `[4]`

Comment: @LPs yep, that's ok, but the point here remains same, better to use `[4]` array.

Comment: @JohnBollinger [edited] sorry it was a typo
        ^

Comment: Add the code that call 'receive_message' function..

Comment: @LPs just added it in the last edit

Answer (score 2):

As @Sourav Ghosh rightly commented you:

```
void build_message(message **msg, int socket, char header[], float *send_value)
{
    *msg = malloc(sizeof(message));
    (*msg)->socket = socket;
    strncpy((*msg)->header, header, 4);
    (*msg)->send_value = send_value; 
    (*msg)->message_buffer = malloc(BUF_SIZE);
}
```

Change the structure to:

```
typedef struct{
    int socket;
    char header[4];
    float *send_value;
    char *message_buffer;
}message;
```

Comment: Still getting segmentation fault here. `(gdb) print message_Ta
$1 = (message *) 0x9293180
(gdb) print message_Ta.message_buffer 
$2 = 0x3a617275 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x3a617275>`

Comment: What is your platform?

Comment: 3.13.0-48-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 12 11:16:18 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
compiling with gcc

Comment: `Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  __strlen_sse2_bsf () at ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/strlen-sse2-bsf.S:50
50 ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/strlen-sse2-bsf.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) up
#1  0x08049dd5 in receive_message (msg=0x9b6ab08) at udp.c:71
71  len = strlen(msg->message_buffer)+1;
(gdb) info local
nread = 134522804
len = 134522384
rc = -1239420116
(gdb) print msg
$1 = (message *) 0x9b6ab08
(gdb) print msg->message_buffer 
$2 = 0x2e363120 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x2e363120>`

Comment: You are using `strlen` on `message_buffer` that is probabl not null terminated. The error is on `receive_message` function

Comment: `sprintf(message_Ta->message_buffer, "%s0.0", message_Ta->header);`
that is the way I am assigning `message_buffer` shouldn't it be null terminated?

Comment: That instruction works well. I tested it. Did you changed the header size to 4 instead of 3?

Comment: yep, I copy and pasted from this answer.

Comment: @user2288551, the error you now describe does not occur in the code you copied from this answer; you have a problem somewhere else.  It looks like you may be using a `message` that was not initialized by the function presented, or whose `message_buffer` member has been corrupted, or whose `message_buffer` member points to memory that has been freed.

Comment: when you say the `message_buffer` may have been corrupted.. how could that happen? (sorry I am a C newbie)

Comment: @user2288551, `message_buffer` could be corrupted if your code writes to `my_message->send_value[1]`, or if it overwrites the end of `my_message->header` by several bytes.

Comment: @LPs I am calling it like: `Ta = receive_message(message_Ta);
`

Comment: @user2288551 Did you capile with `-pthreads` option? Senza questa `malloc` non è thread safe.

Comment: @LPs yes, I am using a makefile and all my object file are compiled with -pthread option including the main file

Comment: Are you sure that `nread = read(msg->socket, msg->message_buffer, BUF_SIZE);` returns always a null terminated string? You have to check return of value 0, that means that the other side of your socket closed the connection.