# Why my free() wrapper function doesn't work?

Tags: c, function, pointers, free

Why should i use pointer to pointer in my saferFree(void**) function when i want to free  memory inside that function? Why below code does'n free ip pointer?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void saferFree(void *);

int main()
{
    int *ip;
    ip = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
    *ip = 5;

    saferFree(ip);

    return 0;
}

void saferFree(void *pp){
    if((void*)pp != NULL){
        free(pp);
        pp = NULL;
    }
}
```

Above code doesn't free pp pointer but below code with double pointer works properly.I want to know Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>



void saferFree(void **);

int main()
{
    int *ip;
    ip = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
    *ip = 5;

    saferFree(&ip);
    printf("%p", ip);

    return 0;
}

void saferFree(void **pp){


    if(*pp != NULL){
        free(*pp);
        *pp = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: Please show the part where you get to see `.It doesn't Free the allocated memory.` Some people are getting confused.

Comment: I suspect the problem is OP expects the pointer `ip` main() to be `NULL` because it's set to `NULL` in `safeFree()`. `pp` is local to `safeFree()`, so it doesn't reflect in main(). See this post as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431108/changing-address-contained-by-pointer-using-function

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, it is perfectly safe to pass NULL to `free()`. Your wrapper is basically meaningless.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.22.3.3, (*emphasis mine*)

> The `free` function causes the space pointed to by `ptr` to be deallocated, that is, made
>   available for further allocation. **If `ptr` is a null pointer, no action occurs.** [..]

---

That said, as per your question, it works fine, but because accessing free-d memory is UB, you should not be doing that (which you seem to be doing in `main()` after calling `saferFree()` to check if the memory is freed or not. ). Also, maybe worthy to mention that the function arguments are passed by value in C, so any change you make to `pp` itself  (example: `pp = NULL;`) will not reflect to `ip` in `main()`. `free()` will work normally, though.

Also, [please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: This seems like a comment for me.

Comment: Where's freed memory accessed?

Comment: @MikeCAT Wait for the OP to edit the question. :)

Comment: @usr for a hint, see the comparison in the code block in `main()`  as mentioned by OP.

Comment: @usr Seen and understood. OP is checking the memory is actually freed or not by attempt to access the memory.

Comment: @SouravGhosh that isn't said anywhere, OP could be just checking if pointer is NULL

Comment: @MarkusLaire The problem is, everyone is very keen on finding secondary issues with the question and answer, while the primary point is, the whole wrapper thing OP is trying to code, is rather useless. Once that is removed, the problem is gone.... :)

Comment: `Why my free() wrapper...`. Stop, you don't need one, or least not _this_ one.