# Why Does my program have Memory Leaks?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to create a small *c program* that will read a string with arbitrary size, without having any memory leaks.

According to my research, the function **malloc** can be used to allocate a number of bytes for whatever data we want to store.

In my program, I start by allocating space for 0 characters, and I make the pointer **word** point to it.  Then whenever I read a single character, I make a pointer **oldWord** that points to **word**, which frees the old memory location once I allocate a larger memory location for the new character.

My research shows that the function **free** can be used to free an old memory location that is no longer needed.  However, I am not sure where I am going wrong. Below you can see my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    char *word = malloc(0);

    printf("Enter name: ");
    readWord(word);
    printf("Your name is: %s\n", word);

    free(word);

    word = realloc(0);

    printf("Enter name: ");
    readWord(word);
    printf("Your name is: %s\n", word);

    free(word);

    return 0;
}

void readWord(char *word){
    int i = 0;
    char *oldWord, c = getchar();

    while(c != ' ' && c != '\n'){
        oldWord = word;
        word = realloc(word, i + 1);
        free(oldWord);
        word[i++] = c;
        c = getchar();
    }

    oldWord = word;
    word = realloc(word, i + 1);
    free(oldWord);
    word[i] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing address contained by pointer using function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431108/changing-address-contained-by-pointer-using-function)

Comment: `realloc` invalidates the passed in pointer. Meaning you shouldn't `free` it, but you will need to free the pointer returned from `realloc`.

Comment: `char *word = NULL;` is much better that `char *word = malloc(0);`

Comment: [`getchar` returns an `int`!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356322/difference-between-int-and-char-in-getchar-fgetc-and-putchar-fputc)

Answer (score 3):

The problem as I see it here is with

```
   free(oldWord);
```

without checking the **failure** of `realloc()`. In case `realloc()` is success, passing the same pointer to `free()` causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That said, some more notes

- a syntax like

  ```
  word = realloc(word, i + 1);
  ```

  is dangerous, in case `realloc()` fails, you'll lose the actual pointer, too. You should use a temporary pointer to hold the return value of `realloc()`, check for success and only then, assign it back to the original pointer, if you need.
- In your code, `c` is of `char` type, which may not be sufficient to hold all the possible values returned by `getchar()`, for example, EOF. You should use an `int` type, that is what `getchar()` returns.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you `free` the pointer you passed to `realloc()`.  This is incorrect as `realloc()` will have freed the memory already if the block was moved.
  Otherwise the pointer is freed twice.
- The pointer reallocated bu `readWord()` is never passed back to the caller.
- Allocating a 0 sized block has unspecified behavior: it may return `NULL` or a valid pointer that should not be dereferenced but can be passed to `free()` or `realloc()`.
- You do not test for end of file: there is an infinite loop if the file does not have a space nor a linefeed in it, for example if the file is empty.
- you do not have a prototype for `readWord()` before it is called.

Here is an improved yet simplistic version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *readWord(void);

int main(void) {
    char *word;

    printf("Enter name: ");
    word = readWord();
    if (word == NULL) {
        printf("Unexpected end of file\n");
    else
        printf("Your name is: %s\n", word);

    free(word);
    return 0;
}

char *readWord(void) {
    int c;
    size_t i = 0;
    char *word = NULL;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && !isspace(c)) {
        word = realloc(word, i + 2);
        if (word == NULL)
            break;
        word[i++] = c;
        word[i] = '\0';
    }
    return word;
}
```

Comment: `malloc(0)` is unspecified whether null pointer or not (not implementation-defined)