# Shifting pointer to some address by calling another function

Tags: c, pointers, function-calls

Why in this code the pointer shifts to another location:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(int *p)
{
        int j=2;
        p=&j;
        printf("%d\n%p\n%d\n",*p,&j,p);
}

int main(void)
{
        int *q;
        int m=98;
        q=&m;
        f(q);
        printf("%p ",q);
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 2
>   0x7ffff5bf1bcc
>   0x7ffff5bf1bcc
>   0x7ffff5bf1bc8

I understand that when the function f() is done with printing value of `j` and **address of** `j` the **memory** occupied by `j` goes back to the stack but IMO `p` should continue pointing that location even after the function is over & it should be printing the **same** address in **main** as well. What is wrong with this?

Comment: This code doesn't even compile, where is `p` in `main` ?

Comment: `printf("%p ",p);`..compilation error.

Comment: Function parameters are local variables to that function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing address contained by pointer using function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431108/changing-address-contained-by-pointer-using-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learn the difference between Pointers and Pointers to pointers - the pointer passed **p** is no doubt good to change the value of the variable it is pointing to (**m**), but to change the memory location it is pointing to - you need a pointer to pointer.

Answer (score 6):

*Considering you meant `printf("%p ", (void *)q);` in the actual code,*

No, function argument(s) in C is (are) passed by value. It won't reflect the changes made to the parameter into the actual arguments used (in function call) themselves.

To put it into other words, the function parameters are local to the function (call) scope, any changes made to them won't be reflected to the actual arguments.

So, if you need to change a *pointer*, you need to pass a pointer to the pointer which needs to be changed.

Consider a rather *light-hearted* but realistic scenario.

```
void f (int x) { x = 10; }

int main(void) { f(5); printf ("%d", 5); return 0;}
```

Now, do you expect it to print `10`?

---

That said, an advice. Always cast the argument to `%p` conversion specifier to `(void *)` (if it is not already). `printf()` is a variadic function and for pointers, no default argument promotion happens, so the supplied argument type needs to match the expected type, explicitly. Otherwise, technically it is  [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on top of what @SouravGhosh said, when you pass in a pointer to an int you are making a copy of the pointer. If you wanted to change the pointer you need to be doubly indirect and pass in a pointer to a pointer to an int. The first pointer is copied and you can directly affect the second pointer.

```
void f(int ** p)
{
    int j = 2;
    *p = &j;
    printf("%d\n%p\n%p\n",*p,&j,p); 
}

int main(void)
{
    int ** q = (int **)malloc( izeof(int *));
    int m = 98;
    *q = &m;
    f(q);
    printf("%p ",q);
    free(q);
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is

> 2
>   0xffffcbcc
>   0xffffcbcc
>   0xffffcbcc

Comment: We might want to add that getting a pointer to a local variable in another function is less than useful. You can't do much with a dangling pointer.

Comment: @BoPersson I'd say, it's __dangerous__. I don;t want to see my laptop on fire (_or, an automatic order of pizza for the whole staff in my office using my credit card_).

Answer (score 0):

If you do this you'll see that it never changes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Header2.h"
#include "header1.h"

#include <stdio.h>
void f(int *p)
{
    int j = 2;
    p = &j;
    printf("%d\n%p\n%p\n", *p, &j, p);
}

int main(void)
{
    int *q;
    int m = 98;
    q = &m;
    printf("Value of pointer q before calling f() =%p ", q);
    f(q);
    printf("Value of pointer q after calling f() =%p ", q);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OK...what am I missing here? How is this an answer? It merely confirms the observation.