# Segmentation fault (core dumped) with malloc and struct

Tags: c, linux, struct, malloc

I can't understand why this simple code doesn't run without causing a segmentation fault on linux :

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct entry
{
   int value;
};

void initEntry(struct entry *entry)
{
  entry = malloc(sizeof(struct entry));    
  entry->value = 0;
}

int main()
{
  struct entry *list;

  initEntry(list);    
  list->value = 5;
}
```

I can run the program after removing the last instruction (`list->value = 5;`)

I compile with :

```
gcc main.c -o main
```

Comment: because in C, everything is pass by value.  so the value `entry` inside `initEntry` is assigned to the return from malloc, but the value `entry` inside `main` never changes.  so you have both a memory leak and a crash.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing address contained by pointer using function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431108/changing-address-contained-by-pointer-using-function)

Comment: Be careful though, the accepted answer suggests to call Malloc inside a function, but better practice is to havr thr base pointer provided by Malloc around in case you need to `free` it

Comment: to change the place a pointer is pointing to, via a function, the address of the pointer must be passed

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc` always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, then call `perror()` with your error message, then both your message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred are output to `stderr`

Comment: Yeah thanks you I'll think about it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change it to:

```
void initEntry(struct entry **entry) {
  *entry = malloc(sizeof(struct entry));    
  (*entry)->value = 0;
}

int main() {
  struct entry *list;    
  initEntry(&list);    
  list->value = 5;
}
```

In your code you just lose the address of allocated memory after returning from the `initEntry()` call. It's because `entry` argument is a local variable regarding the `initEntry()` function and assigning of any values to it is invisible from outside. You need an extra inderection level to be able to *return* the address of the allocated memory.

Comment: The code run but i have these messages during the compilation : `main.c:31:13: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘initEntry’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   initEntry(&list);
             ^
main.c:24:6: note: expected ‘struct entry *’ but argument is of type ‘struct entry **’
 void initEntry(struct entry *entry) {`

Comment: Are you sure that you have adjusted both `initEntry()` definition and the `initEntry()` invocation sides?