# Why am I not addressing correctly my struct element?

Tags: c, pointers

I am getting a bit confusing with pointers, I want to update the variable `tmpTwoComplement`, if I do update as in this code snippet, it does work:

```
int16_t max30205MeasureTemperature(int16_t *tmpTwoComplement) {

    char regT = MAX30205_REG_TEMPERATURE;

    max30205_raw_data rawTemp;

    max30205_read_reg_as_temperature(regT, &rawTemp);

    *tmpTwoComplement = rawTemp.swrd;
}
```

but this one doesn't, why?

```
int16_t max30205MeasureTemperature(int16_t *tmpTwoComplement) {

    char regT = MAX30205_REG_TEMPERATURE;

    max30205_raw_data rawTemp;

    max30205_read_reg_as_temperature(regT, &rawTemp);

    tmpTwoComplement = &rawTemp.swrd;
}
```

I always call the above function as

```
max30205MeasureTemperature(&registerTemp);
```

being

```
typedef union max30205_raw_data {
    struct {
        uint8_t lsb;
        uint8_t msb;
    };
    struct {
        uint16_t magnitude_bits:15;
        uint16_t sign_bit:1;
    };
    uint16_t uwrd;
    int16_t swrd;
} max30205_raw_data;

tempSamplesUpdatedMAX30205 = true;
```

Comment: First one works, second doesn't. Clearly as in C language, there is no `pass by reference`. Your pointer is local variable and you only change where local variable points to. WIth first example (dereference included), you write the data to the memory pointed to by your variable. Even worse, in second example you are trying to assign pointer to local variable.

Comment: refer to [Changing address contained by pointer using function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431108/changing-address-contained-by-pointer-using-function) for details on why the second code doesn't work like you think

Comment: you write "I want to update the variable tmpTwoComplement" however it appears what you actually want to do is update the contents of the memory location whose address is stored in the variable `tmpTwoComplement`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*tmpTwoComplement = rawTemp.swrd;
```

You write the value of `rawTemp.swrd` to the location pointed to by `tmpTwoComplement`, which happens to be the address of the variable `registerTemp` because of the way you call the function: `max30205MeasureTemperature(&registerTemp)`. So after exit from the function, `registerTemp` will contain a copy of the value inside `rawTemp.swrd`.

```
tmpTwoComplement = &rawTemp.swrd;
```

In this case. you copy the *address of* the local variable `rawTemp.swrd` into the pointer `tmpTwoComplement`, overwriting the address of `registerTemp` which was previously in it. After exit from the function, nothing happens because all internal variables of the function cease to exist and your code has not written into any variable outside of the function.

What you should understand is that `tmpTwoComplement` is a pointer to some memory location. You can always make it point to a different location as in your second case. But that, in itself, accomplishes nothing. What you want to actually do is write to the target memory location it *points* to. This is done by using `*tmpTwoComplement=`.

EDIT:
Why don't you do it this way, avoiding pointers altogether?

```
int16_t max30205MeasureTemperature(void) {    
    char regT = MAX30205_REG_TEMPERATURE;

    max30205_raw_data rawTemp;

    max30205_read_reg_as_temperature(regT, &rawTemp);

    return rawTemp.swrd;
}
```

and then read it with,

```
registerTemp = max30205MeasureTemperature();
```

Answer (score 1):

This

```
tmpTwoComplement = &rawTemp.swrd; /* assigning pointer with locally created struct var address */
```

doesn't work as `tmpTwoComplement` assigned with *locally created structure variable address & this scope is within this `max30205MeasureTemperature()` function only*.

When control comes back to here

```
max30205MeasureTemperature(&registerTemp); /* max30205MeasureTemperature modifies registerTemp in second scenario */
```

`registerTemp` no longer points to previews address & now it may not point to valid address.

Comment: Then how do I fix the first case to make it available outside the function `max30205MeasureTemperature()`?

Answer (score 1):

In the second case only the pointer `tmpTwoComplement` is changed. Now it points to the temporary value `rawTemp.swrd`. Since a parameter is working like a local variable, it has no effect at all, because no other expression follows. The variable `registerTemp` at the caller's site is not changed.