# Copy a pointer to a struct in a function (linked list)

Tags: c, list, struct, singly-linked-list, pass-by-pointer

I want to craete a single linked list without gloabal variables. I initialized the first element with `NULL` and then wanted to copy the first element `node` to `list_`. It is copied in the function but the side effect isn´t working. In my main-function the value is still `NULL`.
If I return the struct in the `add_element()`function all works fine but, is it possible that `l` gets the value of node without changing the functions structure and the struct itself?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct list {
        int value;
        struct list *next;
};


struct list *initialize(void)
{
    struct list * l = NULL;
    return l;
}

int add_element(struct list *list_, void *v)
{
    struct list *node = malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    node->value = *((int*)v);
    node->next = NULL;

    if(list_ == NULL)
    {
        list_ = node;
        printf("list_->value = %d\n", list_->value);    // correct copy
        return 0;
    }
    //TODO if not first then  add at end..
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    struct list *l = initialize(); // l = NULL
    int i = 10;
    add_element(l,&i);
    if(l == NULL) printf("l == NULL!\n");
    printf("l->value = %d\n", l->value); // does not work, l is NULL
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing address contained by pointer using function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431108/changing-address-contained-by-pointer-using-function)

Answer (score 0):

**kaylum's comment points you in the right direction.**

When you pass a pointer in C, the pointer's value is copied to the stack, and this copy is the value that the `add_element()` function is referring to.  When you alter the pointer's value, you are modifying the copy placed on the stack, **not the original pointer**.

If you want to alter the original pointer (as if it was passed by reference and not by value) you need to use a double pointer.

Try this variant:

```
    int add_element(struct list **list_, void *v)
    {
        struct list *node = malloc(sizeof(struct list));
        node->value = *((int*)v);
        node->next = NULL;

        if(*list_ == NULL)  // dereferencing the double pointer will access the original pointer
        {
            *list_ = node;  // this will change the original pointer
            printf("(*list_)->value = %d\n", (*list_)->value);    // correct copy
            return 0;
        }
        //TODO if not first then  add at end..
        return 0;
    }

    int main()
    {
        struct list *l = initialize(); // l = NULL  
        int i = 10;
        add_element(&l,&i); // notice you are now passing the address of l instead of its value
        if(l == NULL) printf("l == NULL!\n");
        printf("l->value = %d\n", l->value); //should work now
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, I can understand the problem. But the function structure ```int add_element(struct list *list_, void *v)``` is given. Is it somehow possible to modify the struct s1, which I put in the function?

Answer (score 0):

For starters the function initialize

```
struct list *initialize(void)
{
    struct list * l = NULL;
    return l;
}
```

does not make great sense. You can just write in main

```
struct list *l = NULL;
```

Or the function `initialize` can look like

```
inline struct list *initialize(void)
{
    return NULL;
}
```

The function `add_element` deals with a copy of the passed list.

```
int add_element(struct list *list_, void *v);
```

So any changes of the copy do not influence on the original list. Also it is unclear why the second parameter has the type `void *` instead of the type `int`.

You have to pass the list by reference to the function.

The function can look the following way

```
int add_element( struct list **head, int value )
{
    struct list *node = malloc( sizeof( struct list ) );
    int success = node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        node->value = value;
        node->next = NULL;

        while ( *head != NULL ) head = &( *head )->next;

        *head = node;
    }

    return success;
}
```

and called for example like

```
int i = 10;

if ( !add_element( &l, i ) )
{
    puts( "Error: not enough memory." );
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct list 
{
    int value;
    struct list *next;
};

static inline struct list * initialize( void )
{
    return NULL;
}

int add_element( struct list **head, int value )
{
    struct list *node = malloc( sizeof( struct list ) );
    int success = node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        node->value = value;
        node->next = NULL;

        while ( *head != NULL ) head = &( *head )->next;

        *head = node;
    }

    return success;
}

void output( struct list *head )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", head->value );
    }

    puts( "NULL" );
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct list *head = initialize();

    const int N = 10;

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        add_element( &head, i );
    }

    output( head );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> NULL
```

Pay attention to that if a new node is appended to the tail of the list then it is better to define the list as a two-sided singly-linked list.

Comment: Also thanks, the problem I had is understandable now, but the function structure is given so is it posible to modify the struct I give to the function, when I only put in the ```struct list *head```?

Comment: @langung If the parameter of the function shall be struct list *head then the only approach is to return the modified pointer from the function and assign it to the original pointer head.

Comment: And is it posibble to allocate the memory in the initialize() function and just call the initialize() function in the add_element() function and change/initalize only the value in the add_element() function?

Comment: @langung You can do as you like provided that your code is correct.