# CS50 filter: reflect a bmp image along the horizontal axis using a reflect filter

Tags: c, cs50, reflect

In this assignment I have to edit the piece of code that filters an image. The rest of the code has already been provided and is correct. My code compiles but the image is unchanged and I can't figure out why.

I'm still confused about memory allocation. I don't really understand the difference between malloc and calloc and don't know which is preferable here. I've included a commented out line of code to show that I've tried both ways with the same result. If someone could explain the malloc and calloc and their purpose in this context I'd really appreciate it!

```
// Reflect image horizontally
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE(*tmp)[width] = malloc(height * width * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));
    // RGBTRIPLE(*tmp)[width] = calloc(height, width * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));
    if (tmp == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        // Copy integers from old image into new image
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            tmp[i][j].rgbtRed = image[i][width - (j + 1)].rgbtRed;
            tmp[i][j].rgbtGreen = image[i][width - (j + 1)].rgbtGreen;
            tmp[i][j].rgbtBlue = image[i][width - (j + 1)].rgbtBlue;
        }
    }
    image = tmp;
    free(tmp);
    return;
}
```

Comment: In addition to the explanation regarding your errors given by Some programmer dude, I would suggest to try a completely different approach. You could try to do the task with only 1 temporary triple: `RGBTRIPLE tmp;` instead of an array. You can simply swap the triples in place instead of creating a copy for the result and copying back to intial array.

Comment: Partial dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431108/changing-address-contained-by-pointer-using-function

Answer (score 0):

The [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) function only allocates memory.

The [`calloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) function allocates memory *and* "clears" the memory (setting all bytes to zero).

In short, `calloc` is equivalent to `malloc` followed by a call to [`memset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset).

To be honest, just about any decent book, tutorial or class should have contained this information.

---

Regarding the code you show, you don't need to use `calloc`, since you will overwrite all the memory anyway.

There are however other problems with your code...

The first which is that you forget that in C all arguments are passed by value, which means that the value you use when calling the function is *copied* and inside the function all you have is the copy to work with. So when you, for example, assign to `image` then you only assign to the local copy of the variable. The original pointer you used when calling the `reflect` function will not be modified by the assignment. To solve this problem you need to *copy* the memory from `tmp` to `image`.

Another problem is that you call `free` on `tmp` after the assignment to `image`. If the assignment worked as you wanted to (which it doesn't, see above) then *both* the `image` and the `tmp` pointers would become invalid with the call to `free` (as both pointers are the same and pointing to the same memory). Fortunately this problem is moot once you solved the copying problem, and you can `free` the pointer `tmp` without problem.

Comment: @mich-ish If an answer solves your problem, you might think about accepting and/or upvoting it.