# How to malloc this array in this function and return the array to the main function?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

The following is a problem taken from leetcode: **Two Sum** problem, where a specific target value should be achieved from the sum of any 2 elements in the array and the indices of the two elements should be stored in the return array which should be malloced and returned.

I am getting an error as `'ret is redeclared as different kind of symbol'`.

```
/**
  * Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().
 */
int *twoSum(int *nums, int numsSize, int target, int *ret) {
    int i, j;
    int *ret = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
    for (i = 0; i < numsSize; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < numsSize; j++) {
            if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target) {
                ret[0] = i;
                ret[1] = j;
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: You have the *argument* `ret` and then you also define the *local variable* `ret`. Remove one of them.

Comment: regarding: `int* ret=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*2);`  1) be sure to have the statement: `#include <stdlib.h>`  2) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code and is error prone.  Suggest removing that cast.  3) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful (==NULL) then call `perror( "Your error message" );` to output both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.

Comment: regarding the statement: `for(i=0;i<numsSize;i++)`  Suggest limiting this `for()` loop to: `for( i=0; i< (numsSize-1); i++ )` so as to avoid the variable `j` being equal to `numsSize` for one iteration of the inner loop.  Such a value for `j` causes `nums[j]` to access beyond the end of the array `nums[]` resulting in undefined behavior ( and possibly a seg fault event )

Comment: OT: regarding: `int i,j;`  This is setting the 'scope' of those variables to `file scope`.  However, good programming practice is to limit the 'scope' of variables .  Suggest removing that line and modifying: `for(i=0;i<numsSize;i++)` to `for( int i=0; i<numsSize; i++ )`.  Similar considerations apply to the statement: `for(j=i+1;j<numsSize;j++)`.  Also, note the use of appropriate horizontal spacing for readability.  The compiler doesn't care but humans do care about readability.

Comment: @BShan: you can accept one of the answers y clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you have declared twice in `twoSum` function.

The argument `ret` is a red-herring in any case as you can't assign (i.e. can't return via the passed pointer) an allocated pointer to it that the caller can use - because arguments are passed by value in C (see [Changing address contained by pointer using function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13431108/4389800) for more info on this). Since you're returning the pointer, you just need to remove the argument and rewrite your function.

```
int *twoSum(int *nums, int numsSize, int target)
{
    int i, j;
    int *ret = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
    if (!ret) return NULL;

    /* In case, no such indexes are found. */
    ret[0] = -1;
    ret[1] = -1;

    for(i = 0;i < numsSize; i++)
    {
        for(j = i+1; j < numsSize; j++)
        {
            if(nums[i] + nums[j] == target)
            {
                ret[0] = i;
                ret[1] = j;
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As already said you have two declarations of `ret`. One time in the parameter list

```
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* ret)
```

and another at:

```
int *ret = malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
```

Beside the suggestion from [@usr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4389800/usr) there is another possible way.

If you want to provide a pointer in the caller to which the dynamic memory allocated in the function `twoSum` shall point to, declare `ret` as `int**` and dereference `ret` to assign the pointer in the caller by the address of the allocated memory.

Don´t forget to check if the allocation were successful by checking the returned pointer from `malloc()` for `NULL`.

The returned pointer from `malloc()` do not need to be casted.

```
void twoSum (int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int** ret){

     int i,j;
     *ret = malloc(sizeof(int)*2);

     if (*ret == NULL)
     {
         fputs("Allocation failed!",stderr);
         exit(1);     
     }

     for(i = 0; i < numsSize; i++)
     {
         for(j = i + 1; j < numsSize; j++)
         {
             if(nums[i] + nums[j] == target)
             {
                 (*ret)[0] = i;
                 (*ret)[1] = j;
             }
         }
     }
     return;
}
```

And call it like:

```
twoSum(nums_ptr, numsSize, target, &ptr);
```

Comment: regarding: `(*ret)[0] = i;  (*ret)[1] = i;`  This should be: `(*ret)[0] = i; (*ret)[1] = j;` so setting values from both `i` and `j`

Comment: @user3629249 Uhhh. Thinko. Corrected. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`ret` is coming as an input variable to the function `twoSum`. 
You are redeclaring `ret` in line number 2 with:

`int* ret=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*2);`

Instead you should just do an assignment to it later:

`ret=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*2);`

Answer (score 0):

`ret` is effectively declared twice in the function `twoSum`:

- as the name of the last argument with type `int *`
- as a local variable with the same type.

The error is confusing as both declarations have the same type, but it is nevertheless an error.

Note that the function `twoSum` should just update the array to which it gets the pointer `ret` and return `1` for success and `0` for failure, or some other convention. The posted version keeps searching for solutions even if it found one and always returns `ret`, even if no solutions were found. The caller has no way to tell.

Here is a modified version:

```c
/**
 * Note: The caller must pass a pointer to an array of 2 int
 * the return value is 1 if a solution was found, 0 otherwise
 */
int twoSum(int const *nums, int numsSize, int target, int *ret) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < numsSize; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < numsSize; j++) {
            if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target) {
                ret[0] = i;
                ret[1] = j;
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```