# Confused on pointer and parentheses syntax

Tags: c, pointers

Trying to decipher the following function.
I know `pCfg` is a pointer of any type but I'm not sure what `*(AppBIACfg_Type**)pCfg = &AppBIACfg;` is assigning to the address of `&AppBIACfg`.

```
AD5940Err AppBIAGetCfg(void *pCfg)
{
  if(pCfg){
    *(AppBIACfg_Type**)pCfg = &AppBIACfg;
    return AD5940ERR_OK;
  }
  return AD5940ERR_PARA;
}
```

Comment: `*(AppBIACfg_Type**)pCfg` casts `pCfg` to a pointer pointer of type `AppBIACft_Type`, and then dereferences it, which gives you a pointer to an `AppBIACft_Type`. That explains the "address of" operator in `&AppBIACfg`.

Comment: Its not assigning anything to that address -- it is taking that address and storing it in the location pointed at by `pCfg`

Answer (score 2):

It's taking the address of the global `AppBIACfg` variable and storing that in the memory that `pCfg` points to. The cast is necessary for type correctness.

So if you have something like:

```
AppBIACfg_Type *foo;
AppBIAGetCfg(&foo);
```

it's doing the equivalent of

```
foo = &AppBIACfg;
```

See [Changing address contained by pointer using function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431108/changing-address-contained-by-pointer-using-function)

Answer (score 0):

> Confused on pointer and parentheses syntax

- **`(AppBIACfg_Type**)pCfg`**: Tyṕe casts whatever type is pCfg to a `AppBIACfg_Type` double pointer.
- **`*(AppBIACfg_Type**)pCfg`**: (Note the start star); Dereferences that double pointer, retrieving a single pointer.
- **`... = &AppBIACfg`**: Assigns the memory address of `AppBIACfg` to the single pointer.

So...

That expression assigns the memory address of `AppBIACfg` to a `AppBIACfg_Type` pointer, this type casted from a `void` one.