# Insert to a dynamic array of strings in C

Tags: c, dynamic, malloc, realloc

I'm trying to implement a dynamic array of strings. However I encountered a slight problem. I don't allocate the memory properly, but I have no idea what am doing wrong.

My structure for the dynamic array looks like:

```
typedef struct Array {
    char **ids;
    int size;
} dynamicArray;
```

I initialize it with:

```
void initArray(dynamicArray *array) {
    array = malloc(sizeof(dynamicArray));
    array->ids = NULL;
    array->size = 0;
}
```

Deallocate by:

```
void freeArray(dynamicArray *array) {
    if (array->size != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array->size; i++) {
            free(array->ids[i]);
        }
        array->size = 0;
        array->ids = NULL;
    }
}
```

But now the real problem for me is inserting:

```
void insertArray(dynamicArray *array, char *name) {
    if (array == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    int length = strlen(name) + 1;
    array = realloc(array, (??));
    strcpy(array->ids[array->size++], name);
}
```

The program fails on the reallocation with: `Exception has occurred.`. I'm really not sure, what am I doing wrong. I know I should be also allocating the array of string, but have no idea how to put it in there. Could you guys please send me any hints??

Comment: `initArray()` is not returning the pointer to its caller.

Comment: Show how you're calling `initArray()`.

Comment: If `initArray()` is supposed to allocate the `dynamicArray` structure, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431108/changing-address-contained-by-pointer-using-function. If you're calling it with the address of an existing struct, then it shouldn't call `malloc()`.

Comment: I have `dynamicArray array;` followed by `initArray(&array);`

Comment: And that variable is declared `dynamicArray array;`? Then you don't need to call `malloc()`, the memory is already in the variable.

Comment: You should be allocating and reallocating `array->ids`

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. All the variable declarations matter.

Comment: So I can erase the `malloc(sizeof(dynamicArray));`?? However, how should I insert an element properly?? The strings don't have fixed length.

Comment: Your `realloc` call is making the same error you made in your init function, assuming that `array` itself is the thing requiring dynamic memory to grow...  When in fact, it is `array->ids` that should be passed to `realloc`.  You also need to allocate memory for the strings themselves.  I think perhaps you are jumping ahead too far in your learning with this task, when you should first be learning the basics of memory management in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pointer that you need to reallocate is `array->ids`, not `array`. When you insert into the array you increase its size. Then the new element points to a copy of the `name` string.

```
void insertArray(dynamicArray *array, char *name) {
    if (array == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    int length = strlen(name) + 1;
    char *copy = malloc(length);
    if (copy == NULL) { // malloc failed
        return;
    }
    strcpy(copy, name);
    char **new_ids = realloc(array->ids, (array->size+1) * sizeof(char *));
    if (new_ids == NULL) { // realloc failed
        return;
    }
    array->ids = new_ids;
    array->ids[array->size++] = copy;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works just fine now.