# How can I use struct parameter of a method to assign to another struct in C?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, tree, insert

I am trying to insert values from the binary search tree to linkedlist.

- insertToLinkedList , I am using this method. But there is a problem with assigning.
- struct node
- struct nodeForLinkedList

```
struct node
{// Here node struct for leafs of the Tree
   
    char word[STRING_LEN]; //words
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
   
    
};
struct nodeForLinkedList
{
    
    char word[STRING_LEN]; //words
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
    struct node *next;
    
}
void insertToLinkedList(nodeForLinkedList *nodeL,char *data){
    struct nodeForLinkedList* new_node = (struct nodeForLinkedList*)malloc(sizeof(struct nodeForLinkedList)); 
    
     strcpy(new_node->word, data);                                       // To copy the elements of data to new node's word
    
    new_node->next = *nodeL; // Error occurs here.**(1)**
    *nodeL = new_node;// and here**(2)**


}
```

Errors:

> no suitable conversion function from "nodeForLinkedList" to "node *" existsC/C++(413)  **(1)**
>
> no operator "=" matches these operands -- operand types are: nodeForLinkedList = nodeForLinkedList **(2)**

Comment: Those error messages are for C++, not C.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the declaration of `nodeL` to be a pointer to a pointer, so that you can update the caller's pointer variable.

```
void insertToLinkedList(nodeForLinkedList **nodeL,char *data){
    struct nodeForLinkedList* new_node = (struct nodeForLinkedList*)malloc(sizeof(struct nodeForLinkedList)); 
    
    strcpy(new_node->word, data);                                       // To copy the elements of data to new node's word
    
    new_node->next = *nodeL; // Error occurs here.**(1)**
    *nodeL = new_node;// and here**(2)**
}
```

And when you call the function, it should be

```
insertToLinkedList(&listVariable, stringVariable);
```

See [Changing address contained by pointer using function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431108/changing-address-contained-by-pointer-using-function) for more information.

Comment: Thank u, this is quite helpful.