# How to reference a pointer to structure inside another structure in C

Tags: c, struct, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, dynamic-arrays

I have an assignment in C that basically asks for some sort of interface/database for a supposed animal shelter, and we were given these 2 structures:

```
typedef struct age
{
int years, months;
}age;

typedef struct pet
{
int id;
char* sex;
char* breed;
age* pet_age;
}pet;
```

The interface has to have several functions, like adding a new pet (in our case dogs specifically), removing based on ID, searching for all pets of the same breed and changing the name of a breed entirely, and it all has to be done dynamically using a pet* array as well as the malloc and realloc functions. The entries have to be written in a file and also read from it, but that's something I'll figure out after I figure out how to handle the functions regarding my dynamic array first.

To get to the point, I am having trouble understanding how to scan/reference an instance's pet_age. I've tried it a myriad different ways but I don't understand what's wrong, really. The program crashes/exits after I scan the months element.

Here is the insertion function I have implemented thus far. While not correct, the main source file still compiles.

```
void addPet(pet *p){
    if(i=1){            //First time activation check.
    p=malloc(k*sizeof(p));
    if(!p){
        printf("\nUnable to allocate memory...");
        exit(0);
    }
    }
    p[i].sex = malloc(sizeof(char)*1);
    p[i].breed = malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
    p[i].pet_age =malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
    
    p[i].id = i;    //Autogenerated ID
    printf("\n%d\n", p[i].id);
    
    printf("Insert pet's breed:");  //Scan breed
    scanf("%s", p[i].breed);
    
    printf("Insert pet's sex:");    //Scan sex
    scanf("%s", p[i].sex);
    
    printf("Insert pet's age in years:");   //Scan years
    scanf("%d", p[i].pet_age->years);
    printf("\n%d\n", p[i].pet_age->years);
    
    printf("Insert pet's age in months:");  //Scan months
    scanf("%d", p[i].pet_age->months);
    printf("\n%d\n", p[i].pet_age->months);
    
    i++;    //Incrementing counter
    
    if(i==k){
    k+=10;
    p=realloc(p, k*sizeof *p);  //Size check
    }
}
```

For now there is a basic initialization in the event that this is the first insertion. Then I allocate memory for each element of the structure (to the best of my understanding), and scan every element with a scanf (I pasted some printf checks to see what was actually scanned). Then at the end I increment the i counter, followed by a size check to allocate 10 more places for the array in the event that i==k.

For the sake of continuity, here is my main function as well (basic menu and all):

```
int i=1; //Counter
int k=10;   //Default max entries

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp;
    int choice;
    pet *petarray;
    
    //Menu that lists every option.
    while(1){   //Endless loop that ends only if you choose to exit through the 5th option.
    printf("\n\n Menu:");
        printf("\n=========");
        printf("\n1. Insert information for a new pet.");
        printf("\n2. Delete a pet record based on pet's ID.");
        printf("\n3. Search a pet record based on pet's breed.");
        printf("\n4. Update pet's breed name.");
        printf("\n5. Exit.\n\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1:
            addPet(petarray);
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        case 4:
            break;
        case 5:
            printf("Exiting program...");
            exit(0);
        }   
}
    return 0;
}
```

Apologies if this seems amateur, I'm quite the rookie and still learning. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(char)*1);` doesn't allocate enough memory. You need to allocate room for the null terminator.

Comment: `addPet()` is not updating `petarray`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431108/changing-address-contained-by-pointer-using-function

Comment: `if(i=1)` should be `if(i==1)`

Comment: `scanf("%d", p[i].pet_age->years);` should be `scanf("%d", &p[i].pet_age->years);`

Comment: There are probably lots more problems with your code. You need to go back to your study materials and learn the basics, this is too much for me to fix.

Comment: `p=malloc(k*sizeof(p))` -> `p=malloc(k*sizeof(*p))`

Comment: If `breed`, `pet_age`, etc. exist in each member and are fixed size, why you do `malloc` and not define them as object, array, etc.? `char breed[20]; age pet_age; ...`.

Answer (score 1):

It compiles, but don't you get a long list of warnings? If you don't, you should turn on warnings.

But let's have a look.

```c
void addPet(pet *p)
{
    if (i = 1)
```

You are not comparing (global!) `i` to 1 here. You are assigning to it. This `if` statement can only take the true path because of that. When you assign to `i`, the result of the assignment is the value you assign, so you are testing `if (1)` here. You want to take this path only if `i` is 1, I guess, so you should use `if (i == 1)`.

```c
    { //First time activation check.
        p = malloc(k * sizeof(p));
```

Well, it is *every* time, but we have fixed that now. What do you want `p` to be, here? An array of `k` pets? That is not what you are allocating memory for. You are allocating space for `k` times `sizeof(p)` and since `p` is a `pet *p`, that means you are allocating space for `k` pointers to pets. Not pets. That, of course, is a problem since `p` is a pointer to `pet` and not a `pet **`. You have most likely allocated too little memory here.

This, unfortunately, is usually not something you will get a warning about. You can give `malloc()` any size, and it will give you that amount of memory. If you asked for the wrong amount, you get the wrong amount.  I think you wanted `malloc(k * sizeof *p)` here. That allocates space for `k` of the kind of objects `p` points to, and that means you can use `p` as an array of `k` of that type. You do it the right way when you `realloc()` later, so this is probably just a quick mistake, but it can easily destroy everything at runtime.

```c
    p[i].sex = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1);
    p[i].breed = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
```

Two issues here. First, are you sure that `p` has an entry `i`? If you fixed the allocation above, then the `p` you allocated the first time has room for `k` pets, but this could be any `p` we have called the function with, so we don't know about this one at all. There is absolutely no guarantee that it is valid to access `p[i]`. Your reliance on the two global variables will generally make this very dodgy; you simply cannot assume that the function is called with the specific pointer you allocated memory for a bit earlier.

Second, for the string allocation, there are a few red flags as well. `sizeof(char)` is always 1, so you don't need it. It isn't wrong, really, it just looks odd. And are you absolutely sure that you are allocating enough memory? For `p[i].sex` I find it highly unlikely. You are getting space for exactly one `char`. If you only want one `char`, then that is fine, but you you should probably declare `sex` a `char` instead of a `char *`. If you plan to put a string in `p[i].sex`, then it will have to be the empty string and nothing longer, because you have only room for the `'\0'` terminal in a buffer of length 1.

With

```c
   p[i].pet_age = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
```

it might technically work, but I don't think the standard guarantees it. You are allocating space for a `struct age`, and that struct holds two `int`. They will align the right way, so there shouldn't be any padding, and therefore it should work, but it is flaky as hell.

If you want to allocate space for a `struct`, then do that. `malloc(sizeof(struct age))` gets the job done. Even better, gets the type from the variable you are allocating space for:

```c
    p[i].pet_age = malloc(sizeof *(p[i].pet_age));
```

If `p[i].pet_age` is a `struct age *`, then `*(p[i].pet_age)` is a `struct age`, and it is the size of that we want.

Then we read in the data.

```c
    printf("Insert pet's breed:"); //Scan breed
    scanf("%s", p[i].breed);
```

Here we can have a buffer overflow.

```c
    printf("Insert pet's sex:"); //Scan sex
    scanf("%s", p[i].sex);
```

Here we are guaranteed one, because we need to write the terminal zero into `sex` after we put the data there.

```c
    printf("Insert pet's age in years:"); //Scan years
    scanf("%d", p[i].pet_age->years);
    printf("\n%d\n", p[i].pet_age->years);

    printf("Insert pet's age in months:"); //Scan months
    scanf("%d", p[i].pet_age->months);
    printf("\n%d\n", p[i].pet_age->months);
```

Since `scanf` needs to store the data it reads somewhere, it needs a pointer to where it should put it. You are providing integers. (Your compiler definitely should have warned you here). You should use `&p[i].pet_age->years` to store an integer in `p[i].pet_age->years`, and the same for `months`.

Then we get to what I think is probably the worst error in the code.

```c
    if (i == k)
    {
        k += 10;
        p = realloc(p, k * sizeof *p); //Size check
    }
```

I'm not going to comment on the global variables again, but rather the local variable. This `realloc` potentially destroys the memory that `p` pointed at. I don't care that it can return NULL and you don't check; I doubt that this is happening in your program, but someone called `addPet` with a pointer, and they have no way of knowing if that pointer is valid again after calling. They have to consider it lost. It won't be freed if `addPet()` doesn't free it (and it doesn't), and they cannot safely do it themselves. The new memory you allocate doesn't get back to the caller in any way. Assigning to the local variable in `addPet()` doesn't affect any caller's variable. This `realloc()` is *dangerous*. The caller will absolutely lose the existing memory and has no way of obtaining the new memory.

Any of these issues can be the cause of your current problem; the others can be the cause of future problems.