# code crashes when i use the last pointer in doubly linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, scope, doubly-linked-list, pass-by-value

So I wrote some code for a doubly-linked list and while making a function for adding a node at the end, I thought of making a pointer for the last node, but when I execute it for adding at last it crashes but adding at front end it works fine. Everything looks fine and it does not even show any error but just crashes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *lptr;
    struct node *rptr;
};
typedef struct node *Node;

Node pos(Node first, Node last)
{
    Node new;
    new = (Node)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new->lptr = NULL;
    new->rptr = NULL;
    printf("Enter data: ");
    scanf("%d", &new->data);
    if (first == NULL)
    {
        first = new;
        last = new;
    }
    else
    {
        int p;
        printf("1) First\n2) Last\n");
        scanf("%d", &p);
        switch (p)
        {
        case 1:
            first->lptr = new;
            new->rptr = first;
            first = new;
            break;
        case 2:
            last->rptr = new;
            new->lptr = last;
            last = new;
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    return first;
}
void dis(Node first)
{
    Node p;
    int c = 1;
    if (first == NULL)
    {
        printf("Empty");
    }
    else
    {   p=first;
        while (p != NULL)
        {
            printf("%dst element is %d\n", c, p->data);
            c++;
            p = p->rptr;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int ch;
    Node first, last, t;

    first = NULL;
    last = NULL;
    for (;;)
    {
        printf("Insert: \n");
        scanf("%d", &ch);
        switch (ch)
        {

        case 1:
            first = pos(first, last);
            break;
        case 2:
            dis(first);
            break;
        default:
            printf("invalid");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Think the problem is in this part;

```
case 2:
            last->rptr = new;
            new->lptr = last;
            last = new;
            break;
```

Comment: Unrelated, hiding pointer types in typedefs when learning them as a language or data structures course is literally the most non-"helpful" thing you can do. All it does is obfuscate the code, which is exactly what you do *not* want, especially now.  Regarding your code, look at that while-loop in `dis` and ask yourself what value is held in `p` when the `else` clause is triggered? Hint: there is no defined value. you never initialized `p` to anything, and thus your code invokes *undefined behavior*. I stopped reading after seeing that. Crank up your warnings and treat them as errors.

Comment: `show any error but just crashes.` have you tried on valgrind or to check step by step with gdb ?

Comment: Don't know if it is THE problem, but A problem this code has is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431108/changing-address-contained-by-pointer-using-function with regards to `first` and `last` in `pos`. You solve it for `first` by returning and assigning the new value, but not for `last`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the function  `pos` does not change the pointer `last` declared in `main`. It changes its local variable (parameter) `last` that was initialized by a copy of the value pf the pointer `last` declared in `main`. But the pointer `last` declared in main stays unchanged.

You should declared one more structure like for example

```
struct List
{
    struct node *first;
    struct node *last;
};
```

and use this structure as a parameter of the functions.

```
//...

int pos( struct List *list );

int main( void )
{
    struct List list = { .first = NULL, .last = NULL };

    pos( &list );
    //...
}
```

Also it is much better to split the function into two functions. The first one will add a data to the beginning of the list and the second one   will add a data to the tail of the list.

For example

```
int push_front( struct List *list, int data );
int push_back( struct List *list, int data );
```