# how to double array size (error on second time)

Tags: c++

Some help here, trying to double the array in cpp

on the second resize I got this (messy output)

```
% ./sample
[5] 1 2 3 4 5 
[20] 1 2 3 4 0 6 7 -1610612736 1 2 3 4 14 0 0 0 0 -1610612736 0 0
```

the same removing the memset (to zero's the remaining positions)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void resize(int* v, int* size){ // double the array size
    int newSize = (*size) * 2;
    v = (int *) realloc(v, (size_t) newSize);
    memset(v+(*size), 0, sizeof(int) * (newSize - *size) );
    *size = newSize;
}

int main(){
    int size = 5;
    int* v = new(nothrow) int[size]();

    v[0] = 1; v[1] = 2; v[2] = 3; v[3] = 4; v[4] = 5;

    cout << "[" << size << "] ";
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) cout << v[i] << " "; cout << endl;

    resize(v, &size);
    resize(v, &size);   // <- messy output

    v[5] = 6; v[6] = 7;

    cout << "[" << size << "] ";
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) cout << v[i] << " "; cout << endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

thanks for the help,

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the two languages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing address contained by pointer using function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431108/changing-address-contained-by-pointer-using-function)

Comment: `v` is passed by value to the function. So `v` is a local variable in the `resize` function and setting it does not set the caller's variable. See the duplicate post for more details and options for fixing.

Comment: (a) `realloc` and `memset` each take a size in bytes, but you pass `newSize` to one and `sizeof(int) * (newSize - *size)` to the other. `newSize` is already a number of `int`, not a number of bytes, so do not multiple it by `sizeof (int)`. (b) `resize` cannot return a changed value of `v`; its `v` parameter is a local variable initialized from an argument; changing it does not change the argument. (c) I do not think you are supposed to use `realloc` on pointers obtained from `new`, but I do not follow C++ closely.

Comment: If you are coding in C++, you should not try to mix memory allocations with variants of `new` (and released via variants of `delete`) with memory allocated by `malloc()` et al (and released by `free()`).  Doing so is, AFAIK, UB — it is certainly not supported in older versions of C++ (and probably still isn't supported in newer versions of C++).  In fact, in general, you should not directly manage memory allocation or release in C++.  You should use classes that handle it for you safely.

Comment: Calling `realloc` on a pointer returned by `new` has undefined behavior. If you really want to do this, use `malloc` or `calloc` to obtain the initial memory, but be aware that this works correctly without further adjustments only for trivial types. Also, both the nothrow version of `new` and `realloc` can return null pointers. You must check for that before proceeding to use the pointers. Why are you using the nothrow variant of `new` anyway? If you don't have a very good reason to do all of this, don't do it in C++. Use `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use `malloc()` with `realloc()` or `new` and `delete[]` - not both**

Your immediate problem is you pass a pointer to your function and the function receives a copy -- so any changes made to `v` in the function are made to a local copy of the pointer (which has its own and very different address than the pointer `v` in `main()`)

Another problem is mixing `new` and `realloc()` which results in undefined behavior. Either use `malloc()` in `main()` or manually create and copy in your function using `new` and call `delete[]` on the original before assigning the new block.

Since this is C++, you can solve the problem easily by passing a pointer reference to the function (e.g. `int*& v`) so `realloc()` operates on the original pointer address instead of a copy.

**NOTE:** as JL mentioned in the comment, whenever you call `realloc()` you must assign the result to a temporary pointer which you validate `realloc()` succeeded before assigning to the original. When (not if) `realloc()` fails, it will return `NULL` overwriting your original pointer with `NULL` leaving that block of memory unable to be freed creating a memory leak.

To use a temporary pointer with `realloc()`, you would do:

```cpp
void resize(int*& v, int *size){ // double the array size
    int newSize = (*size) * 2;
    
    /* always realloc with temporary pointer so if realloc fails
     * you don't overwrite your orignal pointer with NULL creating
     * a memory leak.
     */
    int *tmp = (int *)realloc (v, (size_t) newSize * sizeof *v);
    if (!tmp) {   /* validate every allocation */
        perror ("realloc-v");
        return;
    }
    v = tmp;      /* successful realloc(), assign tmp to v */
    
    memset (v+(*size), 0, sizeof(int) * *size );
    *size = newSize;
}
```

Also, in `main()` to use `realloc()` you must originally allocate with `malloc()` (or `calloc()`, or `realloc()`, but not `new`). Further, guard your loop scopes or if you are not going to guard the scope with `{...}` then at least properly indent so your intent is clear, e.g.

```cpp
int main(){
    int size = 5;
    int *v = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof *v);

    v[0] = 1; v[1] = 2; v[2] = 3; v[3] = 4; v[4] = 5;

    cout << "[" << size << "] ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << v[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    resize(v, &size);
    resize(v, &size);

    if (size > 6) {     /* validate size / protect memory bounds */
        v[5] = 6;
        v[6] = 7;
    }
    
    cout << "[" << size << "] ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << v[i] << " ";
    cout << endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

(you should also add `#include <cstring>` for `memset()`)

**Using `new` and `delete[]`**

You can leave your allocation in `main()` as is, if you create a new block in your function with double the size using `new`, copy values to the new block (and initialize the rest to `0`) and call `delete[]` on the original block before assigning your new block to the original pointer.

In that case you would do something like:

```cpp
void resize(int*& v, int *size){ // double the array size
    int newSize = (*size) * 2;
    
    /* create a new block of newSize */
    int *tmp = new(nothrow) int[newSize]();
    /* copy/initialize */
    for (int i = 0; i < newSize; i++) {
        if (i < *size)
            tmp[i] = v[i];
        else
            tmp[i] = 0;
    }
    delete[] v;   /* free original block */
    v = tmp;      /* assign tmp to v */
    
    *size = newSize;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

In either case (`malloc()`, `realloc()`) or (`new`, `delete[]`) the results are the same:

```
$ ./bin/realloc_arr
[5] 1 2 3 4 5
[20] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

In both cases you will want to verify your memory use with `valgrind` or similar memory use/error check for your OS. You will need to add either `free(v)` or `delete[] v` at the end of `main()` to handle freeing all memory you allocate for the purpose of the memory check (it will be freed after the program exits, but without an explicity free in `main()` it will still be shown as in use on program exit.

To use valgrind, just run your program through it. After making the changes above, you would have:

```
$  valgrind ./bin/realloc_arr
==22674== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==22674== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==22674== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==22674== Command: ./bin/realloc_arr
==22674==
[5] 1 2 3 4 5
[20] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
==22674==
==22674== HEAP SUMMARY:
==22674==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22674==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 73,868 bytes allocated
==22674==
==22674== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==22674==
==22674== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==22674== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always ensure all blocks are freed and there are no memory errors.

Comment: If the `realloc()` fails, you've leaked the old memory.  That's not good.

Comment: If the `realloc()` fails we overwrite the original pointer with `NULL` losing the address for the original pointer -- will add a `tmp` pointer.

Comment: Fixing one problem in the code without fixing other critical ones is not a good answer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - what other critical issues are you referring to?

Comment: Read the comments on the question. The code overruns the allocation and has undefined behavior due to passing the result of `new` to `realloc`.

Answer (score 0):

for reference the working version

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void resize(int*& v, int* size){ // double the array size
    int newSize = (*size) * 2;
    int* tmp = new(nothrow) int[newSize]();  // zeroing on the next line is redundant?
    for(int i = 0; i < newSize; i++) tmp[i] = (i < *size) ? v[i] : 0;
    delete[] v;
    v = tmp; 
    *size = newSize;
}

int main(){
    int size = 5;
    int* v = new(nothrow) int[size]();

    v[0] = 1; v[1] = 2; v[2] = 3; v[3] = 4; v[4] = 5;

    cout << "[" << size << "] ";
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) cout << v[i] << " "; cout << endl;

    resize(v, &size);
    resize(v, &size);   // <- NOW, working output
    //resize(v, &size);

    v[5] = 6; v[6] = 7;

    cout << "[" << size << "] ";
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) cout << v[i] << " "; cout << endl; 

    return 0;
}
```