# Why use int** ar and not int* ar?

Tags: c, pointers

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void input(int **ar, int *n) {
    printf("Number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d", n);
    *ar = (int*)malloc(*n * sizeof(int));
    //*ar = new int[*n];
    for (int i = 0; i < *n; ++i){
        printf("Element %d:", i);
        scanf("%d", &(*ar)[i]);
    }
    return;
}
void output(int *ar, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("%5d\n", ar[i]);
    }
    return;
}
int main() {
    int n = 0;
    int *ar = NULL;
    input(&ar, &n);
    output(ar, n);
    free(ar);
    return 0;
}
```

So I have just learned about pointers in C at my university.  Some of it I understand and some I don't.  For example, I don't understand why `ar` in the `input` function is an `int**` and not an `int*`.  I mean I try to replace `int** ar` with `int* ar` and delete the `*` in `int* ar = NULL` in the `main` function and there's no compile error.  When I run the program, everything works fine.  I enter the number of elements and enter some values in those elements but, when I enter the last number in the last element, I get nothing. So I undid everything and the program works normally again.

Comment: "*everything work fine...but i get nothing*". That's a contradiction. It clearly didn't "work fine" if the results are not the expected correct result. It's not clear exactly what you changed but it is definetely wrong. In C there is something called "Undefined Behaviour". Code with UB bugs will result in unpredictable behaviour - e.g. it can crash, get wrong values or even appear to "work". But the behaviour can change at any moment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing address contained by pointer using function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431108/changing-address-contained-by-pointer-using-function)

Comment: As for why `**` is needed please read the duplicate post for details. In summary, you need to be able to return an address allocated inside the function to the caller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program you have posted is doing following (in the given sequence below):

1. Declare/define a pointer in a function
2. Allocate memory to that pointer in some other function and fill that memory with user input
3. Print the content of that memory using another function
4. Deallocate memory and exit

The part which is confusing you is 2.

> I don't understand why ar in the input function is an int** and not an int* ....

If you want to allocate memory to a pointer (or want to change the pointer, like, e.g. making it point to some other memory or reallocating memory etc.) in some other function, you need access of that pointer in that function and you can get access if you have the address of that pointer.
And that's why here the address of `ar` pointer is passed:

```
input(&ar, &n);
```

Pass address of `ar` to `input()` function and in the input function dereference that address (i.e. `*ar`) will give the `ar` pointer (declared/defined in `main()`).
For better understanding, I am renaming the `ar` parameter of `input()` function to `input_ar`:

```
void input(int *input_ar, int *n) {
    .....
    .....
```

When `input()` function called from `main()` function, the in-memory view would be something like this:

```
    input_ar       ar
      +-----+       +-----+      
      | 200 | ----> | NULL|
      +-----+       +-----+

[200 is address of ar pointer]
```

In `input()` function, when you do:

```
*input_ar = (int*)malloc(*n * sizeof(int));
```

dereferencing `input_ar` (i.e. `*input_ar`) will give `ar`:

```
    input_ar      *input_ar (ar)       (newly allocated memory block)
      +-----+            +-----+       +-----+
      | 200 | ---------> | 300 | ----> |     |
      +-----+            +-----+       +-----+

[300 is address of the newly allocated memory block]
```

Hence, by dereferncing `input_ar`, the pointer `ar` can be changed in `input()`.

> I mean I try to replace int** ar with int* ar and delete the * in int* ar = NULL in the main function and there's no compile error.

Note that if you remove the `*` from declaration of `ar` in `main()` then `ar` will be a variable of type `int`, that means, it will not be a pointer but a variable which can hold a `int` type value. If you do this change in your program, you have to make changes in other places as well like, the way you are taking input from user in `input()` function, respective changes in `output()` function etc.

You have not shown the program with the changes that you have done after deleting `*` from `ar` declaration so, I will just talk about the `ar` argument passed to `input()`:

This is what you might have tried:

```
int ar;

input (&ar, &n);
```

and in `input()`:

```
void input(int *ar, int *n) {
    printf("Number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d", n);
    ar = (int*)malloc(*n * sizeof(int));

    .....
```

Note that the `ar` pointer parameter is a local variable of `input()` function.
When `input()` function is called from `main()` function, the `ar` will hold the address of `ar` variable of `main()` function.
If you want, you can make changes in the value of `ar` variable using  the pointer `ar` in `input()` function, e.g. - `*ar = 9;`
This will assign value `9` to variable `ar` (of `main()`). The in-memory view would be something like this

```
    ar (of input())          ar (of main())
      +-----+                +-----+      
      | 200 | -------------> |     |
      +-----+                +-----+

[200 is address of ar variable of main()]
```

But when you do

```
ar = (int*)malloc(*n * sizeof(int));
```

the `ar` has lost the address of `ar` variable of `main()` function and newly allocted memory reference is assigned to pointer `ar` of `input()`, i.e.

```
    ar (of input())          newly allocated memory block
      +-----+                +-----+      
      | 400 | -------------> |     |
      +-----+                +-----+

[400 is address of the newly allocated memory block]
```

You can write/modify the contents in this memory but when returned from `input()`, this memory reference will be lost because `input()` is not returning anything and this will be a memory leak in your program.

Comment: i think the variable in the parameter in the input function should be (int** ar, int* n) right ? not(int* ar, int*n)

Comment: @HTMTYes, since your aim is to allocate memory to `ar`pointer (declared in `main()`) in `input()`, so it should be - (int ** ar, int * n)`.

Answer (score 0):

A common use of pointers, as they're being used here, is to allow a function call to change the value of one of your variables.

For example, suppose you had the following:

```c
void
change_num(int num)
{
    num = 6;
}

int
main()
{
    int num = 5;
    change_num(num);
    printf("%i\n", num);

    return 0;
}
```

This doesn't work because `change_num` is changing its own **copy** of `num` and not `num` itself.

Instead, you have to pass a pointer to `num` to the function:

```c
void
change_num(int* num_ptr)
{
    *num_ptr = 6;
}

int
main()
{
    int num = 5;

    change_num(&num);
    printf("%i\n", num);

    return 0;
}
```

The line `*num_ptr = 6;` means, "Change the object pointed to by `num_ptr` to 6."

In the general case, if we want a function to change the value of a variable of type `SomeType`, then we must pass a `SomeType*` to the function.

In your case, you want to change the value of `ar`, which is an `int*`.  Right now, it doesn't hold the address of anything (`NULL`) and you want it to be changed to hold the value of an allocated array (created by `malloc`).  If we pass an `int*` to a function in order to change an `int` and we pass a `SomeType*` in order to change a `SomeType`, then we must pass an `int**` in order to change an `int*`.