# NEWBIE: passing a pointer to a function

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, function-declaration

I'm trying to relearn C from dabbling with it about 5 year ago. Specifically, I'm trying to learn how to extract a number of operations from main and make them into a function, with the aim of moving them to a library file next.

This seems to be working:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

struct arguments {
  char *word_file;  /* Default name for input file */
} arguments;

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

  arguments.word_file = "dummy";
  
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen(arguments.word_file, "r");
  if (fp == NULL) { /* If fopen failed... */
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Unable to open file %s: %s\n",
        arguments.word_file, strerror (errno));
    exit (8);
  }

  char word[60];
  fgets (word, sizeof(word), fp);
  printf("Word is %s\n", word);
}
```

By the way, 'dummy' is:

```
$ cat dummy
dog
cat
$
```

No matter how I try this, it either gives me compile errors, or seg faults when I run it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

struct arguments {
  char *word_file;  /* Default name for input file */
} arguments;

void getfile(FILE *fp) {  
  fp = fopen(arguments.word_file, "r");
  if (fp == NULL) { /* If fopen failed... */
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Unable to open file %s: %s\n",
        arguments.word_file, strerror (errno));
    exit (8);
  }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

  arguments.word_file = "dummy";
  
  FILE *fp;
  getfile(fp);
  
  char word[60];
  fgets (word, sizeof(word), fp);
  printf("Word is %s\n", word);
}
```

I've tried changing from *fp to fp to &fp without success. I'm sure that there's something that I don't understand about file pointers, but can't figure it out.

Thanks for any help and suggestions.

-Kevin

Comment: C passes arguments by value, so the `fp` in `getfile` is a different variable than the `fp` in `main`.

Comment: The compiler should give you a warning on the line that calls `getfile` that you are using an uninitialized variable. It's important that you enable the compiler warnings, and fix all the warnings. If your compiler is gcc or clang, compile with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices

First, have 'getfile' return the file handle (this is the most idiomatic way in c)

```
FILE *getfile() {  
  FILE *fp = fopen(arguments.word_file, "r");
  if (fp == NULL) { /* If fopen failed... */
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Unable to open file %s: %s\n",
        arguments.word_file, strerror (errno));
    exit (8);
  }
  return fp;
}
```

and in main

```
FILE *fp =  getfile(fp);
```

or have getfile update the fp value based , using c-style 'pass by reference'

```
void getfile(FILE **fp) {  
  *fp = fopen(arguments.word_file, "r");
  if (*fp == NULL) { /* If fopen failed... */
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Unable to open file %s: %s\n",
        arguments.word_file, strerror (errno));
    exit (8);
  }
}
```

in main

```
File *fp = NULL;
getfile(&fp);
```

Comment: thanks so much for your quick response. 
I think the second way you described is what I was thinking of. I would have never got the '**' part. I'll have to study it some more. Thanks, again.

Comment: @KevinZembower you pass a vlue to a functin as an argument, you want it to be updated -> you must pass a pointer to it. In this case the thing you want to pass and have updated is itself a pointer -> pass `&fp`, with arg type `FILE**`

Answer (score 1):

`fp` shouldn't be an argument to `getfile()`, it should be the return value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

struct arguments {
  char *word_file;  /* Default name for input file */
} arguments;

FILE *getfile() {  
  FILE *fp = fopen(arguments.word_file, "r");
  if (fp == NULL) { /* If fopen failed... */
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Unable to open file %s: %s\n",
        arguments.word_file, strerror (errno));
    exit (8);
  }
  return fp;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

  arguments.word_file = "dummy";
  
  FILE *file_ptr;
  file_ptr = getfile();
  
  char word[60];
  fgets (word, sizeof(word), file_ptr);
  printf("Word is %s\n", word);
}
```

If there's some reason you really need to pass it as a parameter, see [Changing address contained by pointer using function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431108/changing-address-contained-by-pointer-using-function)

Comment: Thanks for your really quick reply.
This seems to me to be an unsafe practice. Once the function getfile() is tucked way in a library file, it seems easy to forget that the magic name is 'fp' and someone might rename it 'file_ptr' in the main routine.

Comment: It's not a magic name, you can use any variable you want.

Comment: But don't I have to use 'fp' in both the main function, and the getfile() function?

Comment: No, why would you? It's just returning a value, and then assigning that to a variable in the caller. Why do you think this is any different from the way `fp = fopen(...)` works?

Comment: Wow, you're right, it compiles and works. I'll have to study this to understand it. Thanks, again, for your help.

Comment: Now I see that you're creating two different filepointers, one named 'fp' in the getfile() fucntion, and another one in main called file_ptr. I think I'm beginning to understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the pointer `fp` is passed to the function `getfile` by value.

```
getfile(fp);
```

That is the function deals with a copy of the value of the passed pointer `fp`. So changing the copy in the function does not reflect on the value of the original pointer.

You need to pass the pointer by reference.

In C passing by reference means passing an object indirectly through a pointer to it. Dereferencing the pointer you can get a direct access to the original object.

So   declare and define the function like

```
void getfile(FILE **fp) {  
  *fp = fopen(arguments.word_file, "r");
  if ( *fp == NULL) { /* If fopen failed... */
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Unable to open file %s: %s\n",
        arguments.word_file, strerror (errno));
    exit (8);
  }
}
```

and call the function like

```
getfile(&fp);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick reply. I think this is what I was thinking of.