# How do I assign a new value to a pointer parameter in a void function in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following code:

```
void function(int *c1, int *c2){

    int val1 = 1, val2 = 2;

    c1 = &val1;
    c2 = &val2;
}

void main(){
    int *c1, *c2;

    function(c1, c2);

    printf("*c1=%d, *c2=%d\n", *c1, *c2);
}
```

I need to assign c1 and c2 new values in a function and use them later in main. The function must be 'void'.

I have tried solving this through allocated memory but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't want to return pointers to local variables like `val1` and `val2` anyway.

Comment: You'll want `void function(int*&c1, int*&c2) { static int val1{1}; static int val2{2}; c1 = &val1; c2 = &val2; }`

Comment: Please only tag the language you are using. Removed one of the tags at "random". Fix if I removed the wrong one.

Comment: Tip: `void main()` is wrong. It should be `int main( void )`

Comment: "I need to assign c1 and c2 new values."  There are two different possible interpretations.  Please clarify.  Depending on what you're actually trying to do, it's possible that @ikegami's answer is correct, and the alleged [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431108) is irrelevant.

Comment: @SteveSummit the function is supposed to find 2 indexes, the pointers c1 and c2 are supposed to carry this information to main(). Only the function body can be changed, the parameters must remain the same.

Comment: The `c++` tag was removed, so now my C++ comment is irrelevant.  I'll leave it for posterity, and the lesson learned that mistagged questions and result in comments and answers that are off the mark.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to assign to `c1` and `c2`.

```c
c1 = &val1;  // Wrong.
c2 = &val2;
```

You want to assign to the objects to which `c1` and `c2` point.

```c
*c1 = val1;  // Fixed.
*c2 = val2;
```

---

But there's a second problem. You don't have anywhere to store the `int` values! The variables in `main` shouldn't be pointers at all.

```c
int *c1, *c2;
```

should be

```c
int c1, c2;
```

and that means that

```c
function(c1, c2);
printf("*c1=%d, *c2=%d\n", *c1, *c2);
```

should be

```c
function(&c1, &c2);
printf("c1=%d, c2=%d\n", c1, c2);
```

Comment: at first I was getting a segfault but it was fixed by allocating memory for the pointers. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "allocating memory for the pointers".  If you called `malloc`, that was probably overkill.  I think in the caller you want `int c1, c2` (note no `*`'s) and `function(&c1, &c2);`.

Comment: You should clarify that main() needs to be changed as well. Otherwise they'll just dereference uninitialized pointers.

Comment: @Lundin I had missed that. Added.