# Rust FFI, how to write to passed C pointer (C-like API)?

Tags: c, rust

I'm trying to write a C-compatible API. For this specific call I want to return an error code and receive a pointer which if no error is thrown then points to a struct that will be created.

Here is the code I have which compiles:

```rust
pub extern "C" fn create_engine(mut _qe_ptr: *mut Engine) -> c_int {
    let engine_res = Engine::new();
    match engine_res {
        Ok(v) => {
            _qe_ptr = Box::into_raw(Box::new(v));
            return 0;
        }
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Error creating engine {:#?}", e);
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Engine is also a shared struct between C and Rust, so everything is fine if I instead return a `*mut Engine` pointer from my call. The problem is only when passing a pointer.

The calling C code still has NULL on the pointer after the call finishes executing. Is there any way to achieve this?

```
Engine *qe;
int res = create(qe);
  
if (res != 0) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create engine");
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that should be a pointer to pointer, otherwise you are just reassigning the local variable and not modifying the passed in pointer

Comment: You are _overwriting_ `_qe_ptr` pointer, not _writing_ to its address.

Comment: aha! yeah, I had the suspicion, but I don't know the syntax, could any of you help and post the correct syntax to write to the pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. After reading [some documentation](https://web.mit.edu/rust-lang_v1.25/arch/amd64_ubuntu1404/share/doc/rust/html/book/first-edition/raw-pointers.html) again and understanding that `*mut p` is equivalent to Cs `*p` and looking at how [it would be done in pure C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431108/changing-address-contained-by-pointer-using-function), I understood that I was trying to re-rewrite the pointer instead of changing the pointee value.

The correct answer then would be a pointer to a pointer which can then be overwritten:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn create(_qe_ptr: *mut *mut Engine) -> c_int {
    let res = Engine::new(constructor_options);
    match res {
        Ok(v) => {
            unsafe {
                *_qe_ptr = Box::into_raw(Box::new(v));
            }
            return 0;
        }
        Err(e) => {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's correct, though instead of/in addition to an `unsafe` block, you should mark the function `unsafe`, because it requires the caller to uphold guarantees (pass in a valid pointer) in order to be sound!

Comment: Great tip! Didn't know one could do that! Thanks

Comment: It is better (safer) to take `&mut Option<Box<Engine>>`. The function will automatically be safe to call for Rust code (and no need to mark it `unsafe`), but will also be callable from C, since `&mut Option<Box<Engine>>` is FFI-safe and represents `Engine**` in C.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I tried your suggestion, but it doesn't seem to work or at least I don't know how to re-assign the value inside the Box. Maybe you can post an answer yourself?

Comment: Simple: `*qe_ptr = Some(Box::new(Engine::new(constructor_options)))`.

Comment: Just tried it but it seems `cbindgen` which I'm using to generate the C header does not translate it to a pointer reference, so I'm afraid this is not a solution for my use case, good to know though, thanks!