# C pointer arithmetic applied to function argument

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers

I have a pointer to an array element which is used as an argument in a function and is moved along the array inside said function via the "++" operation. I would like the updated position of the pointer to be re-used after the function's completion.

The following code contains two attempts to solve the issue. The first attempt - via `move_pointer` function - was expanding on an [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431108/changing-address-contained-by-pointer-using-function). Unfortunately, it does not seem to work, the function argument seems unaffected.
The second attempt - via `move_pointer_func` function - works as intended, but I see no way to expand the solution to the case of moving two such pointers at once. As a result, I would appreciate any advice on how the result can be achieved with modifying `move_pointer` function instead.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void move_pointer(const double** pointer){
    *pointer++;
}

const double* move_pointer_func(const double* pointer){
    pointer++;
    return pointer;
}

void check_pointer_movement(const double* input_vec, const int ndim, const bool use_func) {
    const double* input_vec_pointer=&input_vec[0];
    for (int i = 0; i!=ndim; i++){
        printf("%e\n", *input_vec_pointer);
        if (use_func){
            input_vec_pointer=move_pointer_func(input_vec_pointer);
        }
        else {
            move_pointer(&input_vec_pointer);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
   int ndim=4;
   double input_vec[4]={0.25, 0.65, 0.95, 1.2};
   printf("First attempt:\n");
   check_pointer_movement(input_vec, ndim, false);
   printf("Second attempt:\n");
   check_pointer_movement(input_vec, ndim, true);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nicely framed first time question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I see no way to expand the solution to
> the case of moving two such pointers at
> once.

```
        The 2 are equivalent and neither one
            changes 2 pointers at once.
```

#### The problem in `move_pointer()`

```
    void move_pointer(const double** pointer){*pointer++;}
```

Consider this image with code and output side by side (source code is down below)

[image]

This is just a visualization of operators and addresses changing. 32-bit platform is used, just for shorter addresses

#### From the code

```
    p = *ppInt++; // a
    printf("\
        [1] *p is %d\n\
        ppInt now points to 0x%p\n", *p, ppInt);
```

- here `*ppInt` is assigned to `p`
- then `ppInt` is incremented

This way `p` points to `a[]` so `*p` is `a[0]` that is `17`. But `ppInt` was incremented and the next command shows what ran first: `++`

```
    p = *ppInt; // b
    printf("    [2] *p is %d\n", *p);
```

And it prints

```
    [2] *p is 420
```

So `ppInt` was incremented to point to `b[0]`

And now

```
    p = ++*ppInt; // c
    printf("    [3] *p is %d\n", *p);
```

prints

```
    [3] *p is 170
```

because `ppInt` is de-referenced **before** and this value is incremented before being assigned to `p` tha now points to `b[1]`

_

#### back to the original `move_pointer()`###

- `pointer` is incremented
- `pointer` is de-referenced
- the function ends, so this value is not used and `*pointer` is not changed at all

`++` needs to run **at the address pointed by `* pointer`** so
we need to write
`++*pointer` or `(*pointer)++`:

- `*pointer` is evaluated and we still get a `double*`, since `pointer` is `double**`.
- but now the value at this address is then incremented. This value is the `double**` that came from the caller, so the pointer in the caller is updated.

See this table from [cpp reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)
[image]

### Example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void move_pointer(const double** pointer) { ++*pointer; }

const double* move_pointer_func(const double*);

void          check_pointer_movement(
             const double* input_vec, const int ndim);

int main(void)
{
    double input_vec[] = {0.25, 0.65, 0.95, 1.2, 42., 17.};
    int    size        = sizeof(input_vec) / sizeof(input_vec[0]);

    int  a[]    = { 17,  42};
    int  b[]    = {420, 170};
    int* p      = NULL;
    int* pInt[] = {(int*)&a, (int*) & b};
    printf("\
    a[] is at 0x%p\n\
    b[] is at 0x%p\n\
    pInt address is 0x%p\n\
      pInt[0] is 0x%p\n\
      pInt[1] is 0x%p\n",
        &a, &b, 
        &pInt, pInt[0], pInt[1]);
    int** ppInt = (int**)&pInt;
    printf("    ppInt points to 0x%p\n", ppInt);
    p = *ppInt++; // a
    printf("\
        [1] *p is %d\n\
        ppInt now points to 0x%p\n", *p, ppInt);
    p = *ppInt; // b
    printf("    [2] *p is %d\n", *p);
    p = ++*ppInt; // c
    printf("    [3] *p is %d\n", *p);

    printf("\nFirst attempt:\n");
    check_pointer_movement(input_vec, size);

    // 2nd
    const double* fwd = move_pointer_func(input_vec);
    if ( (fwd - input_vec) == 1 )
        printf("Second attempt worked fine!\n");
    else
        printf("Second attempt failed to move pointer forward!\n");
    return 0;
}


const double* move_pointer_func(const double* pointer)
{
    return ++pointer;
}

void check_pointer_movement(
    const double* input_vec, const int ndim)
{
    const double* input_vec_pointer = &input_vec[0];
    for (int i = 0; i != ndim; i++)
    {
        printf("%.2f\n", *input_vec_pointer);
        move_pointer(&input_vec_pointer);
    }
}
```

#### output

```
    a[] is at 0x00AFF9D4
    b[] is at 0x00AFF9C4
    pInt address is 0x00AFF9A8
      pInt[0] is 0x00AFF9D4
      pInt[1] is 0x00AFF9C4
    ppInt points to 0x00AFF9A8
        [1] *p is 17
        ppInt now points to 0x00AFF9AC
    [2] *p is 420
    [3] *p is 170

First attempt:
0.25
0.65
0.95
1.20
42.00
17.00
Second attempt worked fine!
```

#### Notes

#### `move_pointer(double** p)`

```
void move_pointer(const double** pointer) {
    ++*pointer; }
```

This works since the `++` updates the now dereferenced `double**`.

#### `const double* move_pointer_func(const double* pointer)`

```
const double* move_pointer_func(const double* pointer)
{
    return ++pointer;
}
```

Tends to be more practical since it can used to update other pointers or the same pointer.

To test it we can use this expression

```
    const double* fwd = move_pointer_func(input_vec);
    if ( (fwd - input_vec) == 1 )
        printf("Second attempt worked fine!\n");
    else
        printf("Second attempt failed to move pointer forward!\n");
```

Since it is `C` and we increment the pointer by the size of the thing it points to, and we have pointer arihtmetic.

```
    double input_vec[] = {0.25, 0.65, 0.95, 1.2, 42., 17.};
    int    size        = sizeof(input_vec) / sizeof(input_vec[0]);
```

This permits to add values at will to the array and keeps `size` updated

Comment: @KonstantinKarandashev I added code to the example, and text explaining the order of evaluation and some details. There is now a revised example that permits to follow what is changed when. Orignal text was not really correct or clear. Sorry.

Answer (score 6):

The postfix increment operator `++` has higher precedence than the unary dereference opererator `*`.  So this:

```
*pointer++;
```

Parses as this:

```
*(pointer++);
```

Which just increments the local variable.  You want to dereference first, *then* increment:

```
(*pointer)++;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the very quick answer, I already checked that it works!
I will mark your answer as accepted once the necessary time passes.