Having a hard time displaying output from an API
I'm learning how to use openssl and learn more about it.
I wrote a very short line of codes which AES encrypts plaintext and display the output as ciphered text. I had no idea how to display its encrypted plaintext.
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char *buf;
    int num;
    int rn = RAND_bytes(buf, num);

    //if(rn != 1)
    //{
    //  ERR_print_errors(bp);   
    //}

    if(rn == 1)
    {
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
        const EVP_CIPHER *type = EVP_aes_128_cbc();
        const unsigned char *iv;
        unsigned char *out;
        int *outl;
        unsigned char *in;
        int inl;
        iv = buf; // Random numbers from RAND_bytes

        const unsigned char *key = (const unsigned char *)
            "\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07"
            "\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e\x0f"
            "\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17"
            "\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f";
        
        in = "password"; // Plaintext to be decrypted
        ctx =  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new(); // Alocate ctx variable

        EVP_EncryptInit(ctx, type, key, iv);

        EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, out, outl, in, inl);
    
        EVP_EncryptFinal(ctx, out, outl);
        
        const char *ciphertext = out;

        uintptr_t ciphertext_len = (uintptr_t)outl; // Convert pointer type variable to non-pointer type variable

        // Bio dump 
        BIO_dump_fp(stdout, out, ciphertext_len);
        // Clean up 
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    }
    
}

I read openssl documentation and from what I've understand 'BIO_dump_fp' function were used to print out hexadecimal values.

buf and num are both uninitialized. If RAND_bytes calls malloc(), that only updates its local variable, not the caller's variable. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431108/changing-address-contained-by-pointer-using-function

To display the decrypted text, you use the EVP_Decrypt* functions.

out is also uninitialized.
